# Mocking Method of the same class that is getting tested

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I am very new to JUnit Testing and Mockito framework , I have a use case where I want to test the method which internally is calling overloaded method of same class that I need to test. I have written the unit test for first method and want to skip the internal second method call. Below is the code snippet.

Class that need to Be Tested -> EndPointResolver
Testing Method -> getArcadiaResources internally calling overloaded method in line 66 which i need to skip/mock.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGa9t.png

Test Class -> EndPointResolverTest
Here in line 28 and 29 i have created two instances of class one using real object and second using spy object , line 47 i am calling the method that needs to be skipped/mock and line 49 i am making a call to the actual method that needs to be tested but here both the method call are happening. I want to mock/skip the second overloaded method present in line 47 and call only the method present in line 49.
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAJjD.png

Comment: Don't do that. Test the behaviour, not the implementation - test doubles are for collaborators.

Answer (score 0):

It would generally be helpful if you provided the code as a snippet directly here instead of uploading screenshots somewhere.

It's not a direct answer to your question, but.... I would like to understand why you want to avoid calling the real overloaded method? I mean, if the code is executed in production, then the method will be called. And shouldn't the test ensure that the behavior desired in production occurs?

Or does the method do something very special (like call another system) that would require a very special test environment? If so, it makes me wonder if it would be better to mock what is called.

In summary, it would be nice if you could share a little bit more context and explain the reason behind your doing. :)

Comment: Hello, This is not in production, the reason is I want to unit test each method so i want to ignore what overloaded method returns and the second overloaded method is hitting an API call using web client. here is code snippet. The class that need to be tested EndPointResolver
@Component
public class EndPointResolver {